# mistakes excel to latex= Missing number, treated as zero. \end{tabularx}

Tags: pdftex

I use the latest version of TeXStudio and all the latest packages and MiKTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X| *{14}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{13mm}|}}
\hline
Numero de Actividad                                                                                 & {semana 1}    & {semana 2}    & {semana 3}    & {semana 4}         & {semana 5}    & {semana 6}    & {semana 7}    & {semana 8}       & {semana 9}    & {semana 10}   & {semana 12}   & {semana 13}
& {semana 14}   &   \\  \hline
Asignacion de Proyecto                                                                              &   & \cellcolor{yellow}  &   &   &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
Asignacion de proyecto para cada integrante    &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa  acerca del tema  &   &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow}    &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa al marco teórico  &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & & & \\ \hline
Investigacion para materiales de adquisicion  &   &   &  & & & & & & &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & &    \\ \hline
Investigacion para los juegos de niños &   &   &   & & & & & & &  &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcia \\ \hline
Investigación complementaria: asesorías de psicología. & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{2do Cuatrimestre}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
Investigacion acerca de justmind protptyper                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50} &    &   &  & & & & \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Investigación de páginas web, blogs,páginas de juego, etc.  &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          &                          & \multirow{-2}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial}                                                     &                          &                          &                          & & & & \\ \hline
Estructura de la página web                                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}                                                                                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Asesoría con psicóloga &  &   &   & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \multirow{-3}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance}&   &   & & & & &   \\ \hline
Investigación para complementar &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &  \\ \hline
Investigación para página de apoyo  &   &   &   & & & & & & &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial \\ \hline
Asesorias para realizar programas (Juegos Didacticos)   & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &
\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance     &                                  \\ \hline
Desarrolo del sitio web (paginas)                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}& \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial                                                                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} &                          & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial                                           \\ \hline
Sitios web (proyecto finalizado) &   &   &   & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance &   &   & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
Actividades elaboradas                                                                              & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{yellow}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
Fecha de entrega                                                                                    & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{red!50}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
Actividades en proceso                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{cyan!30}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses for your other questions that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: keeps giving errors

Answer (score 1):

Well, you added a wrong definition of `\cellcolor[HTML]{cyan!30}` in your last line of the table. Correct it to:

```
\multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{cyan!30}}
%                             ^^  deleted [HTML]
```

The following code compiles without error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X| *{14}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{13mm}|}}
\hline
Numero de Actividad                          & semana 1 & semana 2 & semana 3 & semana 4 & semana 5 & semana 6 & semana 7 & semana 8 & semana 9 & semana 10 & semana 12 & semana 13 & semana 14 &   \\  \hline
Asignacion de Proyecto                       &   & \cellcolor{yellow}  &   &   &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
Asignacion de proyecto para cada integrante  &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance          &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa  acerca del tema        &   &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow}    &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa al marco teórico        &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & & & \\ \hline
Investigacion para materiales de adquisicion &   &   &  & & & & & & &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & &    \\ \hline
Investigacion para los juegos de niños       &   &   &   & & & & & & &  &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcia \\ \hline
Investigación complementaria: asesorías de psicología. & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{2do Cuatrimestre}}    \\ \hline
Investigacion acerca de justmind protptyper                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50} &    &   &  & & & & \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Investigación de páginas web, blogs,páginas de juego, etc.  &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          &                          & \multirow{-2}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial}                                                     &                          &                          &                          & & & & \\ \hline
Estructura de la página web                                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}                                                                                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Asesoría con psicóloga &  &   &   & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \multirow{-3}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance}&   &   & & & & &   \\ \hline
Investigación para complementar &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &  \\ \hline
Investigación para página de apoyo  &   &   &   & & & & & & &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial \\ \hline
Asesorias para realizar programas (Juegos Didacticos)   & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &
\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance     &                                  \\ \hline
Desarrolo del sitio web (paginas)                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}& \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial                                                                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} &                          & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial                                           \\ \hline
Sitios web (proyecto finalizado) &   &   &   & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance &   &   & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
Actividades elaboradas                                                                              & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{yellow}}                      \\ \hline
Fecha de entrega                                                                                    & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{red!50}}               \\ \hline
Actividades en proceso                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{cyan!30}}             \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

and results in:

[image]