# errors =Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{tabularx}

Tags: tables, tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X| *{14}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{13mm}|}}
\hline
Numero de Actividad                                                                                 & {semana 1}    & {semana 2}    & {semana 3}    & {semana 4}         & {semana 5}    & {semana 6}    & {semana 7}    & {semana 8}       & {semana 9}    & {semana 10}   & {semana 12}   & {semana 13}
& {semana 14}   &   \\  \hline
Asignacion de Proyecto                                                                              &   & \cellcolor{yellow}  &   &   &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
Asignacion de proyecto para cada integrante    &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa  acerca del tema  &   &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow}    &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa al marco teórico  &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & & & \\ \hline
Investigacion para materiales de adquisicion  &   &   &  & & & & & & &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & &    \\ \hline
Investigacion para los juegos de niños &   &   &   & & & & & & &  &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcia \\ \hline
Investigación complementaria: asesorías de psicología. & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{2do Cuatrimestre}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
Investigacion acerca de justmind protptyper                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50} &    &   &  & & & & \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Investigación de páginas web, blogs,páginas de juego, etc.  &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          &                          & \multirow{-2}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial}                                                     &                          &                          &                          & & & & \\ \hline
Estructura de la página web                                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}                                                                                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Asesoría con psicóloga &  &   &   & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \multirow{-3}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance}&   &   & & & & &   \\ \hline
Investigación para complementar &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &  \\ \hline
Investigación para página de apoyo  &   &   &   & & & & & & &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial \\ \hline
Asesorias para realizar programas (Juegos Didacticos)   & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &
\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance     &                                  \\ \hline
Desarrolo del sitio web (paginas)                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}& \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial                                                                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} &                          & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial                                           \\ \hline
Sitios web (proyecto finalizado) &   &   &   & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance &   &   & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
Actividades elaboradas                                                                              & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{yellow}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
Fecha de entrega                                                                                    & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{red!50}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
Actividades en proceso                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{cyan!30}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is that different from your earlier question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474289/121799, which I see just now?

Comment: Can you correct me

Comment: You got an answer by Kurt. I think this answer solves your problem. If not, then please contact Kurt. (I didn't see your earlier question, if I did I wouldn't have posted my answer, and I will be happy to delete it if it in the way.)